# How do I combine loading Firebase list with Value and Child Event listeners in Android?

Tags: android, performance, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

What I would like to have is load initial list once with `addListenerForSingleValueEvent()`, show progress bar while loading, hide progress bar when list loaded, start listening for child item changes with `addChildEventListener()`.

The reason why I need a combination of different loading methods is this:

1) loading with `addListenerForSingleValueEvent()` doesn't provide me with a way to distinguish which items are being updated. Saving previous list and iterating through all items and finding a match for each one might be expensive because lists can grow up to 20k items.

2) loading with `addChildEventListener()` works well but there is no way to know if list has items beforehand and if so when initial list is done loading, hence progress bar can not be shown. Plus there are several other minor reasons.

So my question is what's the best way to achieve my goal? The problem with using both methods is the same list being loaded twice. Is there a way to work around that?

Answer (score 0):

Firebase dedupes the listeners. If there are multiple listeners for the same location/query, it only transfers the data once.

But if you don't trust the system, you can also minimize the overlap by using a limit query:

```
ref.limitToLast(1).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(...
```